# JMeter read / write to CSV Data Set Config

Tags: csv, groovy, jmeter

So I am loading data from CSV Data Set Config, what I like to do is write a value of a variable back into the next column of that same file in the same row but on the next column.

[image]

I check "url" for some specific response json, extract and create a variable "status" and "action" and add it to the row

[image]

Is it even possible to write back to the source csv file? Maybe some post processor script? Searching here is like a needle in a haystack sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but I wouldn't recommend it as if you implement this post-processor logic and run your test with > 1 user most probably you will get into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when several threads are concurrently writing into the same file.

Alternatives are:

1. Adding your `status` and `action` variables values to JMeter's [.jtl result](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) file, just declare the following [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables):

   ```
   sample_variables=url,status,action
   ```

   in the *user.properties* file and next time you run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode you will see 3 extra columns in the .jtl results file holding the values of these 3 JMeter Variables
2. If you want a separate file - first of all execute step 1 and then add a [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) to your Test Plan and configure it to write the variables into a file, the relevant configuration would be something like:

   ```
   variable#0|,|variable#1|,|variable#2|\r\n
   ```